# Cannot connect Xampp server with PHP script

Tags: php, mysqli

I granted all privileges. This is the script:

```
<?php
require_once 'login.php';
$conn =  new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
if ($conn->connect_error) die($conn->connect_error);
?>
```

I have this message in the browser:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\web-datos\connect_mysql.php on line 11
>
> Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YE

I've tried to connect with no success.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: need to check the values assigned to your username `$un` and password `$pw`. Make sure your user you are trying to use is created and the appropriate password is set.

Comment: Well, i did a mistake with the file login.php with the username just i had to change to 'root' thank you for your advice already solve!!!

Answer (score 2):

i believe you cannot connect to your mysql database. you need to grant access to username@localhost.

```
grant all privileges on yourdb.* to username@localhost identified by 'password';
```

if you have not created the user.you can use this command to create new user.

```
create user 'newuser'@'localhost' identified BY 'password';
```

you could also possibly type your user or password wrong.please check it

Comment: yes you have the righ j.Doe, it was it,  and indeed  that is the only hard way to learn from our own mistakes thank you.